# What does a cross mean in lyrics?

Tags: notation, lyrics

The cross appears in a few spots. What does it mean?

[image]

Comment: That's called a "dagger". Normally it is used like an asterisk to refer to a note about the text at the bottom of the page. Are there any footnotes or endnotes on this score?

Comment: Whenever posting a score, please identify the composition and the publisher of the particular edition.  That helps us investigate.

Comment: Given that the first note is tied (?) over from the previous staff, it might be helpful for us to see that staff as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This character is called a `dagger`, and is used to indicate a footnote when the asterisk `*` has already been used. Usually, when there's more footnotes, people tend to use multiple asterisks to indicate to which footnote something relates, but this is another way of doing it.

There's also a double and triple dagger, for when an asterisk and a dagger are not enough for your footnote needs.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger_(typography)